# Understanding Cheerio object and get attributes

Tags: jquery, node.js, cheerio

I am spending so much time trying to read data from an object using `Cheerio`, so i get an object with :

```
  rp(options)
        .then(($) => {
          const listings = $('.listing-cards').first().find(".listing-link");

console.log(listings[0];
```

This will print a very long object which i need only the first part of :

```
{
    type: 'tag',
    name: 'a',
    namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
    attribs: [Object: null prototype] {
      class: ' display-inline-block listing-link\n',
      'data-listing-id': '8026543453',
      'data-palette-listing-image': '',
     href: 'https://www...........link comes here',
     target: '_blank',
     title: 'Product title'
    },
    'x-attribsNamespace': [Object: null prototype] {
      class: undefined,
      'data-listing-id': undefined,
      'data-palette-listing-image': undefined,
      href: undefined,
      target: undefined,
      title: undefined
    },
```

1. How would i get the `title`, and `href` from this object ?
2. What is this object ? is it an array ? what are the rest of the things inside? ( `x-attribsNamespace`, `children`, `next` ? are they come with every object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can do:

```
listings[0].attribs.title
listings[0].attribs.href
```

But it's more common to see:

```
$(listings[0]).attr('title')
$(listings[0]).attr('href')
```

2) It's a parse5 Node object, which is confusing because in jQuery it would be a DOM node.

Comment: Thanks, so that every element in Cheerio, no matter if <a> or <div> will have some certain fields to it ?

Comment: All the node objects have the same properties, and when you wrap them with $() they become Cheerio objects and get extra methods.

Answer (score 0):

This format that you're looking at is how all objects in Javascript are represented. See [`json`](https://developers.squarespace.com/what-is-json).

You can access any field in a `json` object like so:

`obj.fieldname` or, equivalently: `obj[fieldname]`. The second syntax is useful if you know the field name as a string.

So, in your example, you could say:

```
const title = listings[0].title
const href = listings[0].attribs.href //notice there's nested json here. 'attribs' is an object itself
```

As per the second part of your question, those fields do not come with *every* javascript object. You can make an object without those fields quite easily:

```
const obj = {
    myOnlyField: "Hello, world."
}
```

You can probably read the cheerio documentation to see if their library always includes those fields, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! listings[0] .title does not working, also listings[0].attr("href") , this is why i came here. ( i am doing jquery for a year so...  )

Comment: Ah okay! I'd add that to your question then (the two ways that didn't work), so somebody experienced with your libraries can help too haha. Cheers!

Comment: also, if Cheerio is like Jquery, why i can't just ask attr like usual ?

Answer (score 0):

(1) You should refer [cheer.io](https://cheerio.js.org/) documentation. You may try

```
const arrayOfObject = listings.map(function(i, el) {
  // this === el
  console.log($(this).attr('href'))
  return {
    title: $(this).attr('title'),
    href: $(this).attr('href')
  };
}).get();
```

(2) This represents a cheerio object not a plain javascript object/array and Yes, cheerio object has many properties and functions like `attr`

Comment: thanks but wait, i can clearly see here the title and href fields, why i need this map and can't get them using listings[0].title ? that's a normal object, isn't it ?

Comment: Also, why do i need this "Return" in your answer? why is it so complicated to just get those 2 fields without maps ?

Comment: @paulseems as I mentioned in (2), variable `listings` is not a plain Javascript array or object which is cheerio object alike JQuery. Yes you need to return something which you want to get as an array(`get` function will return a Javascript array return from map function), so I returned a Javascript object then `get` will return an array of object, if you return only `$(this).attr('title')` then you will get an array of string

Comment: Once again I would like to recommend you to refer the documentation https://cheerio.js.org/

Comment: thanks a lot but this documentation is very bad and miss a lot(as an engineer myself). But thanks a lot for your help!