# How do you read responses from cheerio?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm having a bit of difficulty figuring out how to read cheerio's responses after running the following:

```
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
axios.get('https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Galar_Route_5')
    .then(({data}) => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(data)

        const tableData = $('table:first').after('span#Hidden_encounters')
        console.log(tableData)
    })
```

When I run the above code I get a quite lengthy response:

```
LoadedCheerio {
  '0': <ref *1> Element {
    parent: Element {
      parent: [Element],
      prev: null,
      next: [Text],
      startIndex: null,
      endIndex: null,
      children: [Array],
      name: 'div',
      attribs: [Object: null prototype],
      type: 'tag',
      namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
      'x-attribsNamespace': [Object: null prototype],
      'x-attribsPrefix': [Object: null prototype]
    },
    prev: null,
    next: Text {
      parent: [Element],
      prev: [Circular *1],
      next: [Text],
      startIndex: null,
      endIndex: null,
      data: 'span#Hidden_encounters',
      type: 'text'
    },
    startIndex: null,
    endIndex: null,
    children: [ [Text], [Element] ],
    name: 'table',
    attribs: [Object: null prototype] {
      class: 'roundy',
      style: 'background: #75C977; width: 30%; max-width: 30%; margin-left: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; border: 3px solid #4AA14D; float:right; text-align:center'
    },
    type: 'tag',
    namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
    'x-attribsNamespace': [Object: null prototype] { class: undefined, style: undefined },
    'x-attribsPrefix': [Object: null prototype] { class: undefined, style: undefined }
  },
  length: 1,
  options: { xml: false, decodeEntities: true },
  _root: <ref *2> LoadedCheerio {
    '0': Document {
      parent: null,
      prev: null,
      next: null,
      startIndex: null,
      endIndex: null,
      children: [Array],
      type: 'root',
      'x-mode': 'no-quirks'
    },
    length: 1,
    options: { xml: false, decodeEntities: true },
    _root: [Circular *2]
  },
  prevObject: <ref *3> LoadedCheerio {
    '0': Document {
      parent: null,
      prev: null,
      next: null,
      startIndex: null,
      endIndex: null,
      children: [Array],
      type: 'root',
      'x-mode': 'no-quirks'
    },
    length: 1,
    options: { xml: false, decodeEntities: true },
    _root: [Circular *3]
  }
}
```

I read through [the docs](https://cheerio.js.org/docs/intro) and there doesn't appear to be anything within them regarding how to read or interpret the response.

I have searched elsewhere (youtube, here, duckduckgo) and I haven't been able to find any resources that actually tell you how to interpret the response.

Comment: This isn't a "response" (HTTP response is usually implied by that term), it's a Cheerio node object. You're not supposed to read it, per se, just call a function to pull out the property you want. For example, `console.log(tableData.text())`. What data are you trying to get, exactly? If you want the table as a data structure, there are many references, for example: [Scraping all rows from table using cheerio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69109537/scraping-all-rows-from-table-using-cheerio/69138324#69138324). Please [edit] the post to show the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is a Cheerio node object<sup>[1]</sup>, not an HTTP response. You don't necessarily need to be able to *read* it, per se, although there is some useful information visible. Just call functions from the Cheerio API, such as `.text()`, `.find()`. `.map()` and so on, to manipulate the object and extract data from it. Ultimately, the idea is to process the Cheerio node tree into some vanilla JS data structure or primitive value(s).

For this example, although you didn't share your goal or desired output, I think you want the following table data, more or less:

```js
const axios = require("axios"); // ^1.6.8
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // ^1.0.0-rc.12

axios
  .get("<Your URL>")
  .then(({data}) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(data);
    const [headers, ...tableData] = [
      ...$("#Hidden_encounters")
        .closest("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6")
        .next("table")
        .find("tr"),
    ]
      .map(e =>
        [...$(e).find("th, td")].map(e => $(e).text().trim())
      )
      .filter(e => e.length > 1);
    console.log(headers);
    console.table(tableData);
  });
```

```
[ 'Pokémon', 'Games', 'Location', 'Levels', 'Rate' ]
┌─────────┬────────────┬──────┬──────┬──────────────┬─────────┬────────┐
│ (index) │ 0          │ 1    │ 2    │ 3            │ 4       │ 5      │
├─────────┼────────────┼──────┼──────┼──────────────┼─────────┼────────┤
│ 0       │ 'Lombre'   │ 'Sw' │ 'Sh' │ 'Grass'      │ '16-18' │ '20%'  │
│ 1       │ 'Nuzleaf'  │ 'Sw' │ 'Sh' │ 'Grass'      │ '16-18' │ '20%'  │
│ 2       │ 'Nincada'  │ 'Sw' │ 'Sh' │ 'Grass'      │ '16-18' │ '5%'   │
│ 3       │ 'Espurr'   │ 'Sw' │ 'Sh' │ 'Grass'      │ '16-18' │ '20%'  │
│ 4       │ 'Spritzee' │ 'Sw' │ 'Sh' │ 'Grass'      │ '16-18' │ '14%'  │
│ 5       │ 'Swirlix'  │ 'Sw' │ 'Sh' │ 'Grass'      │ '16-18' │ '14%'  │
│ 6       │ 'Dewpider' │ 'Sw' │ 'Sh' │ 'Grass'      │ '16-18' │ '5%'   │
│ 7       │ 'Dottler'  │ 'Sw' │ 'Sh' │ 'Grass'      │ '16-18' │ '26%'  │
│ 8       │ 'Applin'   │ 'Sw' │ 'Sh' │ 'Grass'      │ '16-18' │ '10%'  │
│ 9       │ 'Skwovet'  │ 'Sw' │ 'Sh' │ 'Berry tree' │ '16-18' │ '100%' │
│ 10      │ 'Goldeen'  │ 'Sw' │ 'Sh' │ 'Fishing'    │ '16-18' │ '10%'  │
│ 11      │ 'Magikarp' │ 'Sw' │ 'Sh' │ 'Fishing'    │ '16-18' │ '70%'  │
│ 12      │ 'Chewtle'  │ 'Sw' │ 'Sh' │ 'Fishing'    │ '16-18' │ '20%'  │
└─────────┴────────────┴──────┴──────┴──────────────┴─────────┴────────┘
```

More work can be done to group the two 'Games' cells into one, but this at least gets you started and handles the Cheerio part.

Many other threads exist on scraping tables with Cheerio. Taking a look at the following answers should clarify the two-step pattern of scraping rows, then cells with nested `.map` calls as shown above:

- [Basic table scrape example](https://github.com/ggorlen/cheerio-cheat-sheet?tab=readme-ov-file#scrape-a-table)
- [Scraping all rows from table using cheerio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69109537/scraping-all-rows-from-table-using-cheerio/69138324#69138324)
- [Cheerio cannot find table by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68279497/cheerio-cannot-find-table-by-id/75008894#75008894)
- [Parse table from HTML with cheerio in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73509779/parse-table-from-html-with-cheerio-in-node/73614552#73614552)

<sub>[1]: From this similar question as yours, [Understanding Cheerio object and get attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61604230/6243352), this is really a parse5 node object (unless the Cheerio internals or API has changed since 2020, or the linked answer is inaccurate--I haven't verified it). Ultimately, though, I suggest [asking about your fundamental problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676) of how to extract data--the exact object type is probably not important, beyond it being a Cheerio node of some sort.</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, this helps clear things up quite a bit

Comment: No problem, take a look at my [Cheerio cheat sheet](https://github.com/ggorlen/cheerio-cheat-sheet) if you need more examples.